# How to exclude filter results

Tags: r, filter

say I'm using the palmerpenguins  penguins dataset and I want to `filter` out rows in which two conditions are true for example to exclude Adelie species & flipper length <= 190. If I only want to see the results in which both of these are true I would do

`penguins %>% filter(species=="Adelie" & flipper_length_mm<=190)`

I want the opposite. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an opposite formula: penguins %>% filter(species!="Adelie"|flipper_length_mm>190).

Comment: The problem is that if I do that for some reason it filters out all the rows that contain the Adelie species and I only want to filter out the rows in which both those conditions I wrote are true.

Comment: Then use “&” instead of “|”